# remove "isolated" values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I would like to remove (i.e. replace by None) values when the previous and the following rows are None. I cant figure out  a clean way to do it.

## Initial DataFrame:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
|  |  |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

## Target DataFrame:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | 1 |
|  | 1 |
|  |  |
| 1 |  |
| 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

First create the dummy data

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create dummy data. Next time please include this in the question yourself.
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [None, 1, None, 1, 1, 1, 1], "B": [1, 1, None, 1, None, 1, 1]})
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| nan | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| nan | nan |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | nan |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

Then use `shift()` to get the value of the next and previous rows and handle the value in column A accordingly. You can repeat these steps for column B as well.

```py
# For column A store the previous row and next row value in separate columns
# Note that if there is no previous row, you get NaN, which you might need to handle
df["A_prevrow"] = df.A.shift(1)
df["A_nextrow"] = df.A.shift(-1)

# Add a new column where you will replace the value in column A if the previous and the next row is NaN
df["A_corrected"] = df.A
df.loc[(df.A_prevrow.isna()) & (df.A_nextrow.isna()), "A_corrected"] = None
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

| A | B | A_prevrow | A_nextrow | A_corrected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | 1 | nan | 1 | nan |
| 1 | 1 | nan | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | 1 | 1 | nan |
| 1 | 1 | nan | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | nan | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | nan | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You could go about it this way:

```py
import pandas as pd 
from math import *

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [None,1,None,1,1,1,1],
                   'B': [1,1,None,1,None,1,1]})
df.count()
for i in df:
    for j in range(1,df.count()[0]-1):
        if isnan(df[i][j-1]) and isnan(df[i][j+1]):
            df[i][j] = nan

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

When searching for patterns of a limited size, you can make use of the `DataFrame.shift` method.

I use 2 `shift` methods here to capture the entire pattern using `&` to find where all of the conditions are True. Once we construct the boolean mask, we can use `DataFrame.mask` to hide the intended values.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [None, 1, None, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'B': [1, 1, None, 1, None, 1, 1],
})

print(
    df,
    #      A    B
    # 0  NaN  1.0
    # 1  1.0  1.0
    # 2  NaN  NaN
    # 3  1.0  1.0
    # 4  1.0  NaN
    # 5  1.0  1.0
    # 6  1.0  1.0

    df.mask(
         # current row is NaN, next row is not NaN, next row is NaN
        (df.isna() & df.shift().notna() & df.shift(2).isna())
        .shift(-1, fill_value=False) # shift backwards to get mask the not NaN value
    ),
    #      A    B
    # 0  NaN  1.0
    # 1  NaN  1.0
    # 2  NaN  NaN
    # 3  1.0  NaN
    # 4  1.0  NaN
    # 5  1.0  1.0
    # 6  1.0  1.0

    sep='\n\n',
)
```